# How to catch out_of_range exception for range error (vector off-by-one error)

Tags: c++

I am trying to get a custom error  message after a vector off by one error.

I am using code blocks.

```
for (int x; cin>>x; )
    v.push_back(x);

for (int i = 0; i<=v.size(); ++i) //to print values
    cout << "v[" << i <<"] == " << v[i] << '\n';

return 0;
```

I expected that after the error  i<=v.size() I would get an error message,  but instead I get a random error value for the last vector value entered.

Comment: Use ranged passed for loops and you can't have an off by one error.  If you are going to iterate an entire range there is no reason to use a counter loop anymore.

Comment: Please, how would I do that?

Comment: I am a beginer.

Comment: Your loop can be replaced with `int i = 0; for(auto e : v) { cout << "v[" << i++ <<"] == " << e << '\n'; }`

Answer (score 2):

You need to access element using `at()`function.
From the [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/at) :

> Returns a reference to the element at specified location pos, with bounds checking.
>
> If pos is not within the range of the container, an exception of type std::out_of_range is thrown.

So all you need to do is replace element access done with `[]` by `at()`:

```
std::vector<int> vec;

// insert value into v
vec.push_back(...);

// Read your vector by checking out of bound access using .at() method
for (int i = 0; i<=vec.size(); ++i) {//to print values
    std::cout << "v[" << i <<"] == " << vec.at(i) << std::endl;
}
```

You can also iterate through every element of a `std::vector` like this :

```
// Copy each element of the vector into element
for(auto element: vec) {
    // Do stuff
}
```

You can also access const / mutable reference to element in the vector :

```
// Accessing constant reference to every element in the vector 
for(const auto& const_element_ref: vec) {
    // Do stuff
}

// Accessing mutable reference to every element in the vector, potentially modifying it
for(auto& element_ref: vec) {
    // Do stuff
}
```

Comment: Amazing! Thankyou.

Comment: it is only in the title, but question is "How to **catch** the exception"...

Comment: I would not use `it` as name in `for(auto it: v)` , as `it` is too common for iterators, but here `it` is a copy of the elements. Especially as you mention iterators. There are iterators involved behind the scences, but `it` is none

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 Good point. I edited the post to reflect that.